# HyperlinkedModelSerializer and ModelViewSet, could not resolve URL

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```py
# models.py
class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(default="yolo", max_length=100)

# serializers.py
class TestSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Test 
        fields = '__all__'

# views.py
class TestViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Test.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TestSerializer

# urls_v1.py
router.register(r'test', TestViewSet)
test_patterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]

# urls.py
from core.urls_v1 import test_patterns
path('test', include((test_patterns, "test")))

# generated routes:
^test/$ [name='test-list']
^test\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='test-list']
^test/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$ [name='test-detail']
^test/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='test-detail']
```

Error:

```
  File "\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 522, in to_representation
    ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "\rest_framework\relations.py", line 416, in to_representation
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg % self.view_name)

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "test-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.
```

I did include the related model in the serializer's meta, and I didn't touch `lookup_field` either in the view or in the serializer (not that setting it manually seems to have any curative effect).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found at least one possible source of this malady.

In my attempted cleverness of manually versioning my patterns, I didn't realize until `print()`-ing the `url_patterns` of django's resolver, that apparently, whenever the `reverse` lookups happen is prior to whenever imported urls are made available. So at the time of the reverse lookups taking place, the routes that django *later* finds, are at this time not found.

One workaround/solution is to move all URL declarations into `urls.py`, this causes the `reverse` lookups to find all the relevant URLs as expected.

---

At `django.urls.resolvers.py` line 749, I added these statements:

```py
    print("Possibilities:", possibilities)
    print("URLs:", self.url_patterns)
```

I then added a helper to my Test model and ran it in the shell:

```py
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        from django.urls import reverse
        return reverse("test-detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

With my original setup, with the imported patterns:

```py
In [1]: from test.models import Test

In [2]: t = Test.objects.first()

In [3]: t.get_absolute_url()
Out[3]: Possibilities: []
URLs? [<URLResolver <URLPattern list> (admin:admin) 'admin'>, <URLResolver <URLResolver list> (None:None) 'test'>>]
```

I don't understand the URLResolver output exactly, but it appears that it's the Possibilities-list that's important.

Modifying `urls.py` thusly:

```py
router.register(r'test', TestViewSet)
urlpatterns = [
    path('test/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

And it still doesn't work in the shell. Which is weird, but I'm assuming that's because there's some initialization that's supposed to happen with the `router` that I didn't do in the shell.

But during `runserver`, it does work:

```py
Django version 4.2.1, using settings 'core.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Possibilities: [([('test/test.%(format)s', ['format'])], 'test/test\\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$', {}, {}), ([('test/test/', [])], 'test/test/$', {}, {})]
URLs? [<URLResolver <URLPattern list> (admin:admin) 'admin'>, <URLResolver <URLPattern list> (None:None) 'test/'>, <URLPattern ''>>]
```